# Diagonalizing the matrix (if possible)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

> Diagonalize the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0&-4&-6\\-1&0&-3\\1&2&5\end{bmatrix}$ if possible

So I know that I can check to see if this is diagonalizable by doing $A = PDP^{-1}$ but I think I'm doing something wrong when I'm finding the eigenvectors.

The eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = 1, \lambda_2 = 2$

I did $\det(A-\lambda_1 I)\vec{x} = \vec{0}$ and got $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&6\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ which gives me:

$x_1 +6x_3 = 0$

$x_2 = 0$

So I have 2 pivots so I know I will have $\mathbb{R}^2$ columns right?

So I get the eigenvector: $\begin{bmatrix}-6&0\\1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Then I get for $\det(A - \lambda_2I) = \begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\0&1&3/2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ so I get:

$x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_2$

$x_2 = -3/2$

so the eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix}-2&-3\\1&-3/2\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ is this correct or have I messed up on my eigenvectors?

**UPDATE:**

I'm also really confused because would 
$D = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$ and

$P = \begin{bmatrix}-6&0&-2&-3\\1&0&1&-3/2\\0&1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ ?

Comment: This matrix is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$. Thus your eigenvectors should be elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Additionally, your matrix $D$ should be a 3x3 matrix, and $P$ should also be a 3x3 change of basis (invertible) matrix.

Comment: Why is an eigenvector represented by a $\times2$ matrix?

Comment: I thought the eigenvectors columns are always the same amount of **pivot** columns that you have after REF @Christian Also, how can $D$ be a $3 \times 3$ matrix when I have only $2$ eigenvalues.. ?

Comment: @Bernard Because I have $2$ pivot columns in REF.

Comment: This proves only the system has rank $2$ in each case.  But an eigenvector is nevertheless a vector in $\mathbf R^3$ since  your matrix is $3\times 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the eigenvalues of $A$, we want to find $\lambda$ such that $A - \lambda I$ has a nontrivial null space (equivalent to the determinant being 0).

$$A-\lambda I = \begin{bmatrix} -\lambda  & -4 & -6 \\ -1 & -\lambda & -3 \\ 1 & 2 & 5-\lambda \end{bmatrix}$$.

By either row reduction or taking the determinant, we can compute that the eigenvalues are indeed $1$ and $2$. We can find the eigenspaces and thus all of the eigenvectors by computing $Null(A-I)$ and $Null(A-2I)$.

For $\lambda = 1$:

$$A- I = \begin{bmatrix} -1  & -4 & -6 \\ -1 & -1 & -3 \\ 1 & 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$$.

After row reduction we get:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1  & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
which has the same null space as $A-I$.

We then compute the null space by setting up the following system of equations:
The eigenvectors will be $<x_1, x_2, x_3>$ such that the following equations hold:

$x_1 + 2x_3 = 0$

$x_2 + x_3 = 0$

Which is equivalent to...

$x_1 = -2x_3$

$x_2 = -x_3$.

So, taking $x_3 = 1$ (or you could choose any other nonzero value), $E(A, 1) = Null(A-I) = span(<-2, -1, 1>)$

Now, you need to do the same thing for $\lambda = 2$. 
i.e. Find the null space of $A-2I$, and you will have found all of the eigenvectors with eigenvalue $2$. This time, you will find that the null space is of dimension 2. As you will have 3 linearly independent eigenvectors total, $\mathbb{R}^3$ has a basis of eigenvectors of $A$, and thus, $A$ is diagonalizable. From there, you can use this basis of eigenvectors to compute $D$, and use the change of basis formula to compute $P$ and $P^{-1}$.

Comment: The matrix is not necessarily diagonalisable if there are only $2 eigenvalues.

Comment: I did the computation for $Null(T-2I)$ in advance and it is of dimension 2. I was saying that when Shammy does the computation and discovers that $Null(T-2I)$ has 2 linearly independent eigenvectors, in addition to the eigenvector with eigenvalue 1 that I found, then we will have found 3 linearly independent eigenvectors and we will know the matrix is diagonalizable. I certainly did NOT mean that by the fact that the first eigenspace has dimension 1, the second must have dimension 2. Was this not clear in my post? If I did not make this clear, I will most definitely edit my wording.

Comment: The trick is that the matrix has 3 eigenvalues, they just don't tell you. They expect you to figure that out when you find the char. poly. from the $\det (A - \lambda I)$.. You are correct tho @Christian

Comment: Furthermore, the eigenvalues are actually $2,2,$ and $1$.

Comment: Yes, we would say that $A$ has 2 distinct eigenvalues, or we would say: $A$ has 3 eigenvalues including multiplicity (1, 2, and 2). If we had 3 distinct eigenvalues, we would automatically know that this matrix is diagonalizable. As we only have 2 distinct eigenvalues, we need more information to determine if the matrix is diagonalizable. I was using the following condition to determine this: A linear transformation, $A$, is diagonalizable if and only if $V$ has a basis of eigenvectors of $A$. By computing $Null(A-I), Null(A-2I)$, we see this is true in our case.

Comment: @Christian: Now it's quite clear.  I think it's important not  to be ambiguous for beginners.

Comment: @Christian the matrix is indeed Diagonalizable FYI. I tested it with $AP = PD$ and the matrix does in fact have $3$ eigenvalues.